# Spring Cloud Task Launcher who handles failured

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm building a small sample application using a simple task launcher to start new tasks locally `(spring-cloud-deployer-local:2.2.2.RELEASE)`. The code below receives events via a stream and starts new tasks locally as expected.

```
@EnableTaskLauncher
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I want to limit the number of tasks being ran at a time to a say 5. I can configure this with application properties like:

```
spring:
  application:
    deployer:
      local:
        maximum-concurrent-tasks: 5
```

And this works as expected, when there are 5 tasks running and another task is started it throws an exception as expected.

The problem I'm having is the task that failed to start is now lost and there is no "retry" type of action happening.

Who/how/where should I be handling the retry event? I'm just pushing tasks to a stream, is it the responsibility of the service pushing those tasks to push the same task again?

Should I be using something like Spring Batch to manage this?

Comment: perhaps you want to re-tag it with spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-dataflow and remove spring-cloud-stream as I see no relation.

Comment: If you are looking at launching tasks from a stream, take a peak at https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow/README.adoc

Comment: The launching isn't my issue, it's handling the failures due to max concurrent takes being set...

Comment: The task launcher dataflow monitors the max concurrent and holds off launching tasks until the number of concurrent tasks drops below the max.

Comment: that was my expectation as well, but it seems its not holding off tasks but just rejecting them and the rejected tasks never run even when capacity becomes available.